# PSD to XHTML...resolution question

Tags: website-design, resolution, html, slices

I have a PSD designed around 1920 pixel i.e the canvas is 1920 pixel wide by 1110 pixel height. My question is, when slicing:

1. Do I slice it the way it is?

   or
2. Change the image size to a lesser width which will basically
   change the canvas size hence my target screen resolution

Thanks

Comment: Slicing is an antiquated way to go about things. Regardless, what kind of users are you targeting with 1920px wide browsers? That's pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion is to start designing with a grid, for example the 960px pixal grid, load it up in Photoshop and start using that as alignments.

Comment: agreed! - wouldn't recommend designing at 1920px for a website

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to slice, if it's a button you have to slice exactly how it is showing, and if it is background then you have to slice according to your page though it includes bit of html here.

content area, navigation bar, buttons and all plays some role to your 1920px you have to slice exactly what is given.

See this how every single element is sliced in a manner its just an example dont follow this every designer use their own way, its an example only: [Coding from psd to xhtml](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/web-development-tutorials/code-clean-professional-web-design/)

show us your screenshot so better we can help/suggest you, that what you have to do.

Comment: Not like I dont sometimes "slice up" my layouts like he did in that tutorial, but that way how he "slices" the elements.. in his case didn't seem that  good of a way... Lots of separate phases when you could've used slice tool to get every section you need and save them all at once... Otherwise it seemed ok as far as I know.. I mean I read like 4 words.. but, yea.

Comment: attached tutorial is just to make him clear that how each and every designed element took place in design,it is not meant to show how to here. we can not tell him what to do without seeing his design, most of the time i design for 1024 px and content area works with 900px only so what to do with remaining 124px? same case apply with this also 1920px and what about other area blank bg space and all...

Comment: Yea, I have no problem with that. But, because the question was about slicing, I just wanted to make sure that no one would think that this way shown in there is necessarily the way to go.

Comment: yeah i updated my answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the canvas size the same as your target width, then slice. Don't make slices then try to reduce them.